# Separate namespace for Exchange hybrid servers

Tags: exchange, exchange-migration, office365, exchange-hybrid

I read somewhere that you could do the following hybrid deployment.

1) Two dedicated Exchange 2016 "hybrid servers" that are F5 load balanced

2) Create a new namespace called hybrid.contoso.com. (Why would we need a new namespace?)

3) Create internal and external DNS A record for hybrid.contoso.com (same IP addresses?)

4) Publish hybrid.contoso.com through the F5 load balancer. (Is this done on the external F5 or both the internal and external F5. We also have BlueCoat device)

4) Point the existing autodiscover record to hybrid.contoso.com (external). (Again why would we do this? Will that mean clients need to be re-configured?). Can we just use a CNAME to redirect autodiscover to hybrid?

5) Point the existing EWS services to hybrid.contoso.com (external). (I supposed this is used for mailbox migration path?)

6) Create two A records called smtp1.contoso.com and smtp2.contoso.com and configure send and receive connectors in Exchange online to send contoso.com mails to these smart host addresses. (I don't know why this is needed cause we are enabling centralised transport and I though this would be created automatically)

Thank you.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what your end goal is and what your definition of "hybrid" is, because it sounds like you're making this more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. yes I was looking at that diagram - Jaaps blog with the hybrid server. I just wanted to know if I can created a "hybrid" server just for mailbox moves and smtp traffic to Office 365 without any disruption. The cook book I read stated creating a pointer to autodiscover.contoso.com called hybrid.contoso.com. Apparently this would "bypass" the 3rd party spam-filter and 3rd party mail gateway" and created a "direct" connection to EOL. The questions above are in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, agree with joeqwerty, “Maybe you can tell us what your end goal is “.

In general, you don’t need to use a dedicated  namespace called hybrid.contoso.com. This hybrid namespace is nothing more than a dedicated namespace for hybrid functionality. By doing so, I prevent having to point client access traffic to the new servers and possibly disrupt my existing environment. I can then use the Hybrid Server(s) only     for mailbox moves, hybrid mail flow etc.

[image]

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. yes I was looking at that diagram - Jaaps blog with the hybrid server. I just wanted to know if I can created a "hybrid" server just for mailbox moves and smtp traffic to Office 365 without any disruption. The cook book I read stated creating a pointer to autodiscover.contoso.com called hybrid.contoso.com. Apparently this would "bypass" the 3rd party spam-filter and 3rd party mail gateway" and created a "direct" connection to EOL. The questions above are in brackets

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the link?

1. You can use a separate hybrid URL, but not recommend.
   https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2015/08/10/hybrid-deployment-best-practices/
   We have seen deployments where a decision is made to keep the existing Mail.Contoso.com and Autodiscover.Contoso.com pointing to a bank of Exchange 2010 servers and have a new hybrid URL, such as hybrid.Contoso.com, pointing to a couple of Exchange 2013 servers. This is an example of an environment that did not introduce Exchange 2013 in a recommended way.

Similar case: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7232e37b-c2df-4e63-b649-e63ef0b5b5b1/separate-hybrid-url-required?forum=onlineservicesexchange

2. Create internal and external DNS A record for hybrid.contoso.com (same IP addresses?)
   No, if you use F5, it should be internal and external IP address for F5.
3. Apparently this would "bypass" the 3rd party spam-filter and 3rd party mail gateway" and created a "direct" connection to EOL. 
   Don’t put any 3rd party spam-filter and 3rd party mail gateway between Exchange on-premises and Exchange Online. 
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/manage-mail-flow-on-office-365-and-on-prem

I didn’t know why to configure as this, and we strongly suggest you follow official deployment.